# Flutter + Firestore: How to get a Stream of a subcollection from a Firestore Query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a Stream of subcollection from a query result in Firestore in my Flutter app:

```
employees
|_employeeId
  |_linkedUserUid(String)
  |__timeLogs(Collection)
      |_docs
```

My employees collection has a field called `linkedUser` that is a String with the UID of the employee. (The employee's doc ID is different than the userID, since not all employees are users)

Under each employee doc is a sub-collection called `timeLogs`

In my Flutter app, I am first trying to query the employees collection to find the employee doc related to the user, then trying to find the subcollection `timeLogs` and then trying to create a list of a custom class I made for the time logs. I can't get it to reach the second function:

```
getTimeLogs(String uid) async {
    employeesCollection.where('linkedUser', isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
        return doc.reference.collection('timeLogs')
            .orderBy('timestamp').limit(10)
            .snapshots().map(_timeLogListFromSnapshot);
      });
    });
  }

List<Timelog> _timeLogListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    print('Here !');
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Timelog(
        timestamp: doc.data["timestamp"],
        type: doc.data["type"]
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

I have been using this Stream to model many times in the app that really works well, for example:

```
// Employees Stream
  Stream<List<Employee>> get employees {
    return employeesCollection.snapshots().map(_employeeListFromSnapshot);
  }
  // Employees List
  List<Employee> _employeeListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Employee(
        eId: doc.data["eId"],
        employeeCode: doc.data["employeeCode"],
        fName: doc.data["fName"],
        lName: doc.data["lName"],
        docId: doc.documentID
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

I want to achieve the same but for that query -> nested collection method. Any advice, or approach on how to do this?

Comment: Since there are asynchronous operations taking place, it would be assistive if you could add "await" to unwind the call chain and also more Logging for debugging purposes to find out where the issue relies.